# Facebook Permissions for user access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LLWT.jpg)[Facebbok Permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaVo1.jpg)

HI,

I am not able to see all permission while getting user access token. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Your app seems to be in “live” mode.

You will need to put it into dev mode to be able to select additional permissions in Graph API Explorer, that you have not gotten reviewed yet.